# Where would you place Backbone View related code that needs to be run after insertion in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

From what I understand of the way Backbone.js is intended to be used, Views are supposed to be rendered in their own `$el` element, which is not necessarily attached to the page. If it is so, the higher level view they depend on usually takes care of inserting the `$el` in the page.

I am making this statement after having read the [Todo sample application](http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html). In this case, the TodoView renders element in a default `div` element that is not attached to the page.

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // [...]
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
    this.input = this.$('.edit');
    return this;
  },
```

The AppView, upon a Todo creation, takes care of creating the TodoView and appending its `$el` to the page after rendering.

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // [...]
  addOne: function(todo) {
    var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
    this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().$el);
  },
```

---

My question is: If a view not attached to the page needs adjustments **after** being inserted (e.g. calculating its position in the viewport and performing DOM manipulation accordingly), where would you place the corresponding code?

Would you create a `afterInsertion()` method that the sublevel View should call after inserting, would you put the code at the same emplacement that where the insertion takes place (i.e. in the sublevel View) or would you change the way the view works to have it rendering directly in the page? I'm sure there are other solutions I can't think of right now. I would like to know what you consider being a best practice/optimized in the way Backbone should work, or if this question doesn't make sense to explain why.

Comment: CSS is the solution for you. The element of backbone view can have the CSS class. After inserting to the view, CSS will take care of positioning the element appropriately. is that the answer for your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. In my specific case, I have a bootstrap3 affix header (becomes fixed top when you scroll past it). The header is appended to the page by my AppView, but I need to define the value in pixels of the breakpoint where the header transitions to a fixed one. I can't know the position before inserting it to the page, since its position in pixels will vary depending on the user's viewport.

Comment: In the case of fixed element, you can insert the element anywhere and positioning the element all respect to the window.
For example:-
           $(body).append(appView.$el); 
will just work if the element is fixed positioning.

Comment: `$('#header').attr('data-offset-top', $('#header').offset().top)` is the line of code I need to run. The `$('#header').offset().top` is meaningless if the header has not been inserted in the page, hence the need to run the code after insertion.

Comment: these two lines can still be after where you insert the element right?? will it not work?

Comment: Currently, I have a ´postInsertion()` method in my AppView that gets run after everything has been rendered and inserted in the page. What bothers me is that this line of code is in the main application view: it concerns a specific subcomponent (header view), so I feel it should be with this component instead.

Comment: If that is your concern, then have a method inside the view. call the method from outside. I am not sure Backbonejs giving this kind of hook method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that it is probably not part of Backbone. I thought maybe this was a common issue and there was some sort of convention or something. Thanks for the help, though =)

Comment: My solution in the end will be to have the main view send a custom event when everything is inserted and have component views subscribe to this event...

Comment: One suggestion to your solution is, if you know about the receiver, you can very well call the method instead of throwing events. I always prefer events when i am unsure of receiver.

Answer (score 1):

I keep track of my sub-views. In a base view definition, create an `add` method:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    // It is really simplified... add the details you find necessary
    add: function (name, viewDef, options) {

        options = options || {};

        if (!this.children)
            this.children = {};

        var view = new viewDef(options);

        this.children[name] = view;
        this.listenToOnce(view, 'ready', this.onSubViewReady);

        view.render(options);
        view.$el.appendTo(options.appendTo || this.$el);      

    }

});
```

With this, you can keep track of your subviews and make anything you want with them later.
If you feel like making things "automatic", you can trigger a `ready` event after your render method doing this:

```
var extend = BaseView.extend;

BaseView.extend = function (protoProps, staticProps) {

    var child = extend.apply(this, arguments);

    child.prototype.__render__ = protoProps['render'] || this.prototype.__render__ || function() {};

    child.prototype.render = function () {

        this.__render__.apply(this, arguments);

        this.trigger('ready', this);

    }

};
```

With this you can do a lot already.

Just remember that the DOM won't be drawn by the time that `ready` is triggered. So, if you are willling to do any calculations with the subview height or anything that needs the DOM to be drawn, use `setTimeout(function () { ... }, 0)` to put your code to the end of queue.

Hope I've helped.